# Generate Key Pair type x25519 with Public Key Enconding as SPKI and Private Key Encoding as PKCS8 using System.Security.Cryptography in C#

Tags: c#

This is the code in node.js for what I trying to reproduce in C#:

```
const nodeCrypto = require('crypto');
// from: https://github.com/digitalbazaar/x25519-key-agreement-key-2019/blob/master/lib/crypto.js

const {publicKey: publicDerBytes, privateKey: privateDerBytes} = nodeCrypto.generateKeyPairSync(
                'x25519',
                {
                    publicKeyEncoding: { format: 'der', type: 'spki' },
                    privateKeyEncoding: { format: 'der', type: 'pkcs8' }
                }
            );
```

This is the code that I am using but the private key is exported as same publick key encoding that is SPKI:

```
public static ECCurve Curve25519 { get; } = new ECCurve() // Curve25519, 32 bytes, 256 bit
{
    CurveType = ECCurve.ECCurveType.PrimeMontgomery,
    B = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
    A = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x07, 0x6d, 0x06 }, // 486662
    G = new ECPoint()
    {
        X = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9 },
        Y = new byte[] { 0x20, 0xae, 0x19, 0xa1, 0xb8, 0xa0, 0x86, 0xb4, 0xe0, 0x1e, 0xdd, 0x2c, 0x77, 0x48, 0xd1, 0x4c,
    0x92, 0x3d, 0x4d, 0x7e, 0x6d, 0x7c, 0x61, 0xb2, 0x29, 0xe9, 0xc5, 0xa2, 0x7e, 0xce, 0xd3, 0xd9 }
    },
    Prime = new byte[] { 0x7f, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff,
0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xed },
    Order = new byte[] { 0x10, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x14, 0xde, 0xf9, 0xde, 0xa2, 0xf7, 0x9c, 0xd6, 0x58, 0x12, 0x63, 0x1a, 0x5c, 0xf5, 0xd3, 0xed },
    Cofactor = new byte[] { 8 }
};
private static void Main()
{
    using (ECDiffieHellmanCng x25519 = new ECDiffieHellmanCng())
    {
        // we have to generate the key explicitly using the curve we defined, the auto-generated keys can not be used
        x25519.GenerateKey(Curve25519);

        // assign what algorithms for derivation and hashing should be used
        x25519.KeyDerivationFunction = ECDiffieHellmanKeyDerivationFunction.Hash;
        x25519.HashAlgorithm = CngAlgorithm.Sha256;

        // save the keys
        byte[] publicKey = x25519.PublicKey.ToByteArray();
        byte[] privateKey = x25519.ExportPkcs8PrivateKey();

        // Now you can save or use the public and private keys
        // For example:
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("public_key.spki {0} ({1})", string.Join(", ", publicKey), publicKey.Length));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("private_key.pkcs8 {0} ({1})", string.Join(", ", privateKey), privateKey.Length));
    }
}
```

But is not generating Curve25519 key pair with size 32 bytes, the code exports the keys in apparently different formats, from which the raw keys would have to be extracted first I guess, but how?

Comment: ECDH and X25519 are based on different algorithms. Also, ECDH uses a short Weierstrass curve and X25519 Curve25519, a Montgomery curve. As far as I know, there is no built-in .NET support for X25519, i.e.  you need a third-party library, e.g. C#/BouncyCastle.